# node express routing to capture all

Tags: regex, express

expressjs. guide says use this:

```
//captures all (equivalent to '.*')
router.get('[[\\s\\S]]*', function);
```

However I cannot get this to work.

I am trying to route:
/k4Kfe or /dHG43 or /rest12 or any other route to go here:

```
app.use ('[[\\s\\S]]*', routes);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try `[\da-zA-Z]+`, the two classes are not required, try `[\\s\\S]*`

Comment: I don't see that code in the express guide. Where did you find it?

Comment: It is in http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html under app.params

Comment: Since my app.js has app.use('/',router) and my index.js I havein teh bototm after admin, login, ogout routes are defined I am trying to go for everything else to this function, I am gettng: This webpage has a redirect loop

ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Answer (score 1):

```
router.get('*', function)
```

Should match all get requests, or you could use:

```
router.all('*', function)
```

to [match all HTTP methods](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.all).

Alternatively you could use [middleware](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.use) using (app.use) and just pass in the routes/function.

```
app.use(routes)
```

See the [Express router docs](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#router) for more examples.

Comment: ["Since path defaults to “/”, middleware mounted without a path will be executed for every request to the app."](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.use) - Why not simply omit the path?

Comment: True, I'll update my answer to include the example - app.all / router.all could also be used too, right?

Comment: When I use '*' in my router.get('*', function)  I get This webpage has a redirect loop

ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: As I mentioned above, try using router.get('*', function) , omitting the path should only work for middleware (app.use).

Comment: Even with  router.use('*', function) I get This webpage has a redirect loop

ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS